# How can I rigorously prove that such a subset of $R^3$ has the topology of a Möbius band?

Tags: general-topology

The band is defined as a quotient topological space, considering equivalence relation in $[0,1]^2$.
We do this by first letting $M$ be the partition of $I^2$ formed by the equivalence relation:
$(1,x)∼(0,1−x)$ where $0 \leq x \leq 1$
and every other point in $I^2$ is only related to itself.

There is a topology result that says that if $f:X→Y$ is an identification between topological spaces, and in $X$ we consider the equivalence relation $R$ that identifies points of $X$ when they have the same image by $f$, then $f$ descends to a homeomorphism of $X/R$ into $Y$. In this case, I can use this idea to produce a quotient homeomorphism of $[0,1]^2$ on the surface of $R^3$.

I consider the product topological space $Ω=[0,2π]×[−0.3,0.3]$ and define the equivalence relation that gives me a Möbius strip.

How do I show that the equivalence relation that I have defined in $Ω$ coincides with what is mentioned, the one that relates points with equal images?

Comment: You have not actually defined an equivalence relation on $\Omega$, so it's not clear how to answer your question.

Comment: "on the surface of $\mathbb R^3$." Which is it? You did not define anything.

Comment: I have a parameterization that visually gives me the Mobius strip in the space [0,2π]×[−0.3,0.3] and I want to show that it has the same topology as the Mobius strip, asking my initial question: How could I get my equivalence relation only having the space and the parameterization? Or some examples to understand well what to do